# Oracle Database monitoring: Replication working or not?

Tags: oracle

How to define database replication is working or not by using Oracle data guard?

`select max(sequence#) a from v$log_history;`

we got primary and standby database last log sequence# from this query.

If the log sequence# differ from primary to standby database then can we say that replication is working or not? If any other way to know the replication status then let me know.